# How to handle Error 500 coming back from asmx service

Tags: web-services, asmx, custom-errors

I have a standard asmx service on which GET is not allowed.

If I visit the asmx `http://mysite/myservice.asmx/myoperation` in the browser (GET) I get a stack trace flushed to the client and I can see from fiddler it's a 500 internal system error. None of my code is being hit.

I have a requirement not to show a stack trace if the url is visited from the browser, so I'd like to redirect to a custom error page I have in place.

I have an Application_Error on the global.asax but its not kicking in in this particular instance.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you disable GET requests via

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <webServices>
         <protocols>
            <remove name="HttpPost"/>
            <remove name="HttpGet"/>
            <remove name="Documentation"/>
         </protocols>
      </webServices>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: mmm, interesting if I remove GET in the web.config as you suggest then it works (goes to the error page), but I cannot do it there 'cause some of the other service need to allow GETs

Comment: can I do something like that at the service level rather than application level?

Comment: @JohnIdol: you can put the SOAP services under a deeper folder and put the above in a web.config in that folder (or use the `<location>` element to specify that the above only apply to the subfolder).

Comment: ok that's an option. any idea why <remove name="HttpGet"/> causes the Application_Error method on global.asax to catch the error 500? I tried with 'UseHttpGet = true' at the webmethod level but it doesn't have the same effect. weird.

Comment: @John: no idea. I try very hard not to use ASMX services any more.

Comment: yeah, me too. found it in place and gotta deal with it.