# Why is my web service getting a 500 error after server move?

Tags: web-services

I have an asp.net web app that dynamically generates an XML file and sends it to a .asmx web service.  Things were great in development but when everything was moved to a production server, I get a 500 error.

Background:

The development server is using IIS 7.
The production server is either using IIS 7 or 7.5.

Is there a setting or something that I am missing in the production server, or in the Web.config file?

I believe the problem might have to do with connectivity issues but cannot prove it.  Plus, I'm a bit rusty on my netwroking as to how I would prove that the problem lies in connectivity and not in the application itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the Web.config... or any sort of log errors.  Do you have any config settings or files you can post along with your question?

Comment: nothing special in web.config. i mentioned it because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646123/how-to-handle-error-500-coming-back-from-asmx-service